# Bounding Geodesic Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth surface, let $p,q \in \Sigma$ and let $n_{p}$ be the normal at $p$. Suppose that $d(p,q) < c$ for some constant $c$. That is $p$ and $q$ are pretty close to each other on $\Sigma$. Consider the plane $h = \operatorname{span}\{n_{p}, \vec{pq}\}$. The intersection $h \cap \Sigma$ defines a curve $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$. I want to bound the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$. I have a bound on the principal curvatures in a neighborhood of $p$. This allows me to bound the normal curvature of $\gamma$. I want to bound the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$, so that I can bound the total curvature of $\gamma$. Is there a way to leverage the principal curvatures at $p$, the fact that $\gamma$ lies in a plane defined above, and the fact that $p$ and $q$ are close on $\Sigma$ to bound the geodesic curvature $k_{g}$ of $\gamma$?

Comment: I assume $\Sigma\subset\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Yes, $\Sigma$ is a subset of $R^3$.

Comment: You mean $" binding "$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is the unit normal to the plane (pointing in the direction of $n_p\times \overrightarrow{pq}$), then 
$$k_g = \kappa(A\cdot n).$$
(One way to see this is to use the formula $(A\times T)\cdot(n\times T) = \left|\begin{matrix} A\cdot n & A\cdot T \\ T\cdot n & 1 \end{matrix}\right|$. Here $A\times T$ will be the principal normal of the plane curve $\gamma$.)
This checks since the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ at $p$ is in fact $0$.

Now, if we define $\theta$ (up to sign) by $A\cdot n = \cos\theta$, then we will have 
$$k_g = \kappa \cos\theta \quad\text{and}\quad k_n = \kappa\sin\theta,$$
so $$\kappa = \frac{k_n}{\sin\theta} = \frac{|k_n|}{\sqrt{1-(A\cdot n)^2}}.$$

Is this something useful for you?

Comment: This might be useful, yes. Thank you, I'll give this a shot when I next get a chance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the expression for $k_g$ is true? You said you can see it using that determinant, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @user354894: So $k_g = (\kappa N)\cdot (n\times T) = \kappa (A\times T)\cdot (n\times T)$. Remember that we're talking about a plane curve $\gamma$ in the plane with normal vector $A$, so its principal normal is $\pm A\times T$.

Comment: Then wouldn't $k_g = \kappa N \cdot (n \times T) = \kappa (A \times T) \cdot (n \times T) = (A \cdot n) - (A \cdot T) (T \cdot n)$ which is not equal to $\kappa A \cdot n$?

Comment: @user308088 You dropped a $\kappa$ there. But the other term is truly $0$, as both of those dot products are $0$.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right that $A\cdot T = 0$ since $T$ always lies in the plane. But $T \cdot n$ is not necessarily equal to zero, as $n$ is the normal on the surface which does not always lie in the plane $h$.

Comment: @user308088 Stop and think. $T$ is the unit tangent to a curve contained in the surface.

Comment: Oh... damn. Cool thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to remember curvature relations.

The component curvature vectors are given by **k** , where **k  = kg  + kn**, the latter two vectores are orthogonal

They are like forces  in vector combination / resolution on the surface points of curve in $\mathbb R^3$.

$$k^2 = k_g^2 + k_n^2 $$

which are the curvature, geodesic and normal curvature components. Non-geodesy when $(\theta =0) $ the curve becomes a geodesic. Components  can be found as:

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{ k_g}{k_n} \quad \text{or} \quad \sin \theta = \frac{ k_g} {k}. $$

Comment: This really did not address the question.